# OS synchronization between computers

Tags: windows-7, networking, sync

Is there a way to synchronize two windows 7 computers (like Dropbox but this time for the entire OS preferences*)?

*Wherever possible.

Comment: What???????????

Comment: Dropbox syncs only files, I guess there is a programm that (via Lan/wifi/etc) synchs things such as desktop background, folders etc

Comment: If you use Windows 8, Microsoft says it'll synchronize PC settings over OneDrive. I've never tried it out though. What you want to sync is mentioned under "Other settings" as "Other Windows settings". It says `File explorer, mouse printers and more` however, I'm not sure what "and more" actually entails.

Comment: On Windows 7, I guess your best bet is to use the [Windows Easy Transfer tool](http://www.7tutorials.com/what-windows-easy-transfer-how-backup-your-data-transfer). Credits to [`harrymc`](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) for [the answer](http://superuser.com/a/478685/167187)